# How do I group a list of numbers based on fixed recurrance

Tags: r

I have a list:

```
x <- c("1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3","2", "2", "2", "2")
```

What I need to do is make them shortened like this.

```
1 2 3 2 3 2 2
```

This is done because after 1, 2 appears 2 times and then 3 appears 3 times and then 2 appears 2 times and so on. This is fixed and it will not change.
I have done this in an if else condition but that seems a bit too much for this. I'm hoping for some guidance on achieving this in a quick way.

---

**Notice** the last two 2s at the end of expected output. Another example to illustrate the expected output:

```
input:  3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2
output: 3,3,2,2,2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `rle()` and repeat each value according to the ratio of its length to value.

```r
with(rle(x), rep(values, lengths / as.numeric(values)))

# [1] "1" "2" "3" "2" "3" "2" "2"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  inverse.rle(modifyList(a<-rle(as.numeric(x)), list(lengths = do.call("/", a))))
[1] 1 2 3 2 3 2 2
```

Comment: Thank you but it has missed the last 4 elements where it is 2,2,2,2. This should be generated as 2 and 2 separately.